# How to allow users access to overwrite files on server Python Flask?

Tags: python, flask, permissions, seaborn

I'm making a simple Flask app that displays different graphs given different inputs from users. The app uses Seaborn to generate the graph, then save it in a directory on the server, then the Flask app will display that image file.

There has been no issue when I try out different input, which alters the graph and overrides the image file, if I were to connect to the server using the local host. However, if I were to connect to the server from a different machine using a web address, it will display the same graph because the server doesn't allow the override of the image file.

I use this code from Seaborn to save the graph image file

```
<seaborn_graph_object>.figure.savefig(<directory>)
```

Comment: Do you need to save the file to disk? You could just keep it in memory and send the base64-encoded data directly to the page. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I tend not to write files when serving one-off plots like this.

For example, when you make the plot, do this instead:

```py
import BytesIO
import base64
import maptlotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make your plot like you normally do.
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])  # Simple example.

# Put plot in memory.
handle = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(handle, format='png')
plt.close()

# Encode.
handle.seek(0)
figdata_png = base64.b64encode(handle.getvalue()).decode('utf8')
```

Then in the app you would do:

```
from flask import render_template

render_template('index.html', plot=plot)
```

And in `index.html` you'd have something like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ plot }}">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I was only starting to use Flask, so I didn't even know this was an option. I will try it out and update you the result!